# why does ruby throw syntax error when attempting an yield within a block?

Tags: ruby

I was exploring the yield keywords and its usage in ruby. While it's completely possible to pass a block to a method implicitly and call the same via yield, when I try to pass another block to the yielded block:

```
def test
  yield { p 'yield2' }
end

test { |&b| p 'in yield1'; b.call }
```

ruby complains with a syntax error:

```
yield.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end
  yield { p 'yield2' }
                     ^
```

Why is this difference of treat with yield and why is this treated as a syntax error?

Comment: My Ruby also complains about the `unexpected '{'` right after `yield`

Comment: Yes @Stefan removing it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the cleaned up version:

```
def test
  x = -> { p 'l1' }

  yield -> { p 'yield2' }
end
```

Note that `yield` is a keyword, not a method call, so you need to be more explicit. You can't just slap a block on there and call it done, it has to be a proper `lambda`.

Then in your call, you can't break out the block, it's just a regular argument:

```
test {|b| p 'in yield1'; b.call }
```

Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a block argument to `yield`, Ruby simply doesn't allow that.

Instead, you could use an explicit block argument and pass the block to [`call`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Proc.html#method-i-call):

```
def test(&block)
  block.call { p 'yield2' }
end

test { |&b| p 'in yield1'; b.call }
# "in yield1"
# "yield2"
```